# Two-Factor Authentication for Microsoft Office Document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, authentication

I have a particularly sensitive Microsoft Office document on my computer (Excel Spreadsheet). I have password protected it, but to feel truly secure, I would like set up two-factor authentication for this document.

Here is what I imagine this looking like: when I try to open the document, I enter the password, and then I enter a code received from a text or an authenticator app. If the code is not entered successfully, the document doesn't open.

Does two-factor authentication for opening a single Microsoft Office Document exist?

Comment: This is not currently a feature that Microsoft Office supports.

Comment: some (non-negligible) infrastructure would be required to do what you request, so even if MS provided the option, it would require an IT team to implement. Instead, consider external cryptography, so that the user must have more than one password in order to access the file. It would be much more secure, in that offline cryptographic exploits would not be able to expose the data unless both the external and internal cryptography was bypassed. documents can't dynamically encrypt themselves, so your scheme would be vulnerable to any exploit that breaks MS crypto regardless of 2-factor.

Comment: A simple way of encrypting a single file is to create a virtual HDD (.VHD) within Windows, mount that virtual HDD, then encrypt the mounted virtual volume.  This allows you to encrypt individual files and folders use the solution you prefer with the added benefit that you can now provide that single file to people.  It also allows you to backup that single file, sync that file to cloud services, since in reality it is a single file.

Comment: Use Windows Server to setup a user account that is part of a network where all activity is monitored. To access the file you want to protect a person must use Remote Desktop to connect to user that's a part of a network. Make two factor authentication a requirement of logging in the network.

Comment: Try paying for Zoho Workplace with the Workplace Professional plan that has the feature you're looking for. https://www.zoho.com/workplace/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly from an office document. You could potentially host the document on a server which requires 2-factor auth to allow downloads but once the document has been opened, it's out of your control and can be copied/shared.

This is why companies offering secure data rooms exist. Depending on your needs, you could host this data through a virtual data room: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_data_room#Virtual_data_room_vendors